# Преимущества WebApi перед Asp.net mvc при реализации api

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Добрый день! Возник следующий вопрос. Имеется asp.net mvc приложение, работающее с некой бд (sql server). И есть еще одно приложение, для которого нужно дать некий api для работы с первым приложением (по большому счету с его базой данных). Предполагается что api должно представлять собой набор http методов, позволяющих получать ответ в формате json. Напрашивается использование технологии ASP.NET Web Api, про которую я слышал ранее. Проблема вот в чем. Я почти ничего не знаю об этой технологии (ну только что она позволяет достаточно легко и удобно создавать такие api и более "легкая" по сравнению с wcf). Пока что я вижу более простую для себя альтернативу в виде создания дополнительного контроллера в своем asp.net mvc приложении с экшнами, возвращающими JsonResult. Ну в общем такая простенькая реализация api. Преимущество такого подхода для меня состоит в том, что в этом случае не придется создавать новый проект и разворачивать его отдельно (мелочь но все же) а также что в mvc приложении доступ к данным происходит через orm и в случае с web api придется как-то дублировать код этого доступа и в web api проекте.

Теперь сам вопрос: есть ли какие-то весомые преимущества у технологии web api для решения данной задачи? Или наоборот есть ли какие-то существенные недостатки для решения этой задачи у подхода с отдельным контроллером и экшнами возвращающими JsonResult? Просто меня гложет сомнение что раз существует такая технология как WebApi,то наверное реализовывать свой api с помощью такого кустарного метода как простые Json-экшены несколько глупо? Наставьте пожалуйста на путь истинный! заранее спасибо!

Comment: Web API это лишь дополнение к ASP.NET (ну или точнее вообще самостоятельная часть). ASP.NET вы как использовали, так и будете использовать, только обращение к контролллерам изменится и всё. Просто посмотрите. Сделайте Hello World и всё станет ясно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**WEB API** крайне удобен для создания *RESTful*-сервисов, который Вам как раз и нужно будет создать. Есть у него и свои нюансы, если **MVC** сочетает в себе и контроллеры и движок представления, то Web Api - это только контроллеры, возвращающие данные (JSON, XML или др. - не важно), которые работают с HTTP. Вы не сможете, к примеру, выполнить переадресацию пользователя на другую страницу, но вы можете послать *HTTP*-код, соответствующий редиректу. Вы не сможете отобразить ошибку авторизации, но вы пошлёте на клиент статус-код, в котором покажете ошибку 401 и сообщение к нему.

Абсолютно без разницы как и на чём вы будете писать клиентское приложение - ведь **WebApi** - это *HTTP*-стандарт.

Но если не брать в расчёт такие понятия как вид выводимых данных - то то, что происходит в контроллере - практически ничем не отличается от обычного **MVC**! Так что не стоит переживать о том, что не сможете использовать **ORM**.